# Custom folder order in Gnome Files

Tags: sort, nautilus

Is there a way to arrange the elements of a folder, specifically folders within that folder, in a specific order chosen by the user? (I have the settings so that folders appear first btw)

I am trying to have an analogous ordering in my folders as I had on MacOS where you can tag them and visually group them by their tags. Have endlessly googled for a package that can do that but I have come up empty handed.

Was thinking of just changing the icon of folders for different colored ones,  but all the different colors are too visually messy so if I could give a custom order for my folders to appear to match the icon's color would be great.

I am using debian 8 with GNOME 3 and whatever the default file manager is.

Comment: I think it would help to know what window manager and file explorer (or whatever they're called nowadays) you're using.

Comment: I edited to add that information, I am using gnome 3 and I don't know what the default file manager for it it is, but I haven't changed any of that.

Comment: The main problem is that the file manager of your chice has some data on which it can arrange your desired order. Without knowing OSX I think they provided such either within the underlaying file system or the file manager stored it in its own configuration. AFAIK none of the current linux file systems supports "tagging" of files or folders. So your best bet is a linux file manager which does...

Comment: Timothy Truckle, are you saying it can't be done?

Comment: `nautilus` supports tagging of files, just right-click on any file/directory and select `properties` from the context menu, the last tab is `tags`. Though I don't think you can sort by `tags` unless you write your own `nautilus` extension. You could also try `nautilus` emblems (google for it) - I've never tried so no idea if you can sort by emblems... worth checking though.

Comment: You can't sort by tags and I already use emblems, that's how I was able to change the color of the folders but is just too visually messy given the amount of colors I need to use.